# iframe height Adjust to Content (working Safari, not on Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, safari

Ok, hey.

I'm trying to get the content of the iframe to adjust the height of the iframe to show all of the content.. in the iframe.

This is the code I have borrowed, it's working on Safari, but it's not working on my darling Chrome;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getDocHeight(doc) {

doc = doc || document;

var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 

    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

return height;

}

function setIframeHeight(id) {

var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);

var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;

ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';

ifrm.style.height = "10px"; 

ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + "px";

ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

</script>
```

and here is the iframe;

```
<iframe src="http://google.com/" 
iframe id="ifrm" name="ifrm" src="height1.html" 
onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)" 
frameborder="0" width="100%" height="0" >
</iframe>
```

Thanks :)